# continuing permutations from a certain point using itertools

Tags: python, permutation

I have a large set of permutations I'd like to run off and on.

```
from itertools import permutations
perms = permutations([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16], 6)
```

I'm using a simple next call to keep the memory usage down.

```
combination = perm.next()
processing = True
while processing:
     try:
         # using combination in code then end by calling next
         # do_work(combination)   
         combination = perm.next()  
     except:
         print(combination) # (0,1,2,3,4,23)
         processing = False
```

All this works fine. But I notice that if I stop it I have to start over from the beginning again.
Is there a way to continue from the last point I was running?

For example:

```
(0,1,2,3,4,23)
```

where the next work be:

```
(0,1,2,3,4,24)
```

?

Update: Many great solutions! Thank you all

Comment: You could track how many runs you've done, save that number, and then throw away that many values next time using `itertools.islice(seq, start)`

Comment: *"I have to start over from the beginning again"* - Not true.

Comment: Just make sure you keep `perm` in scope, and then you don't have to restart at all.

Comment: Are you ever going to show us a [mre] demonstrating that alleged having to start over?

Comment: Kelly, all I can suggest is that you reread the question as everyone else seems to know what's going on besides yourself. You seem to think my non-minimal snippet persists permutations.  Are you having trouble with next? use __next__() Anyway, I'm close to figuring this out based on @BallpointBen 's comment.

Comment: I guess "everyone else" doesn't include @trincot then? Cause he also said you don't have to restart. Not sure about the others. Though I have a suspicion now. What exactly do you mean with "stop"?

Comment: Oh and the problem with your snippet isn't that it's not minimal but that it's not complete. You're not showing how you "start over" after "stopping", whatever that means.

Comment: Kelly, I'm initializing  the permutation at that top. If I were to rerun it it would obviously start again from the beginning.

Comment: So you're talking about running the script multiple times?

Comment: Lol, yes.. I see your confusion but my question was how can I add to my code to make it persist upon stopping. Anyway, I got two great solutions.

Comment: @KellyBundy After running for over a year I've finally recovered my bitcoin wallet! Get it now?

Comment: Get *what* now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a class that manages the permutations and behaves like a list:

```
from math import factorial
from collections.abc import Sequence
class Permutations(Sequence):
    
    def __init__(self,data,samples=None):
        self._data    = data
        self._samples = samples
        self._size    = 0
        self._lenData = 0

    def __len__(self):
        if self._lenData  != len(self._data):
            self._lenData  = len(self._data)
            samples        = min(self._lenData,self._samples or self._lenData)
            self.size      = factorial(self._lenData)//factorial(self._lenData-samples)
        return self.size
    
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        if isinstance(index,slice):
            return map(self.__getitem__,range(len(self))[index])
        scale     = len(self)
        remaining = list(self._data)
        result    = []
        for p in range(min(self._lenData,self._samples or self._lenData)):
            scale //= (len(self._data)-p)
            i,index = divmod(index,max(1,scale))
            result.append(remaining.pop(i))
        return tuple(result)
```

The class uses no additional storage except for a couple of integers to manage size change.  It even supports on the fly changes to the referenced list.

Example use:

```
L = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16]
P = Permutations(L,6)

len(P)   # 5765760
P[6]     # (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11)

for perm in P[6:16]: print(perm)

(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 13)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 16)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9)

for perm in P[-3:]: print(perm)

(16, 15, 13, 12, 11, 8)
(16, 15, 13, 12, 11, 9)
(16, 15, 13, 12, 11, 10)
```

To pickup where you left off you can either store an index or a permutation.  Because the class behaves like a list you can get the next index from a known permutation using the bisect module:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

lastPermute = P[123]              # (0, 1, 2, 3, 16, 6)
i = bisect_right(P,lastPermute)
print(i)                          # 124
```

You can even use it to get random permutations without having to generate them all in a list:

```
random.choice(P)
(9, 7, 10, 5, 2, 4)    

random.sample(P,3)
[(15, 0, 13, 8, 10, 9), (9, 13, 3, 4, 8, 10), (1, 12, 0, 3, 6, 9)]
```

Comment: Nice class, but I need the length of the array to be 6 with the max value of 16.

Comment: I guess that `len` isn't going to be such a common thing to do, so I suggest to move the size calculation inside `__len__`. Also, if you define `__len__` and `__getitem__` you don't need to define `__iter__`.

Comment: Adjusted the class to support a number of samples.

Comment: @AlainT. FYI your latest change broke your code.

Comment: Probably an intermediate save, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You could pickle it into a file and reload it to continue the next run.

Start using it:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations, islice
>>> perms = permutations([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16], 6)
>>> *islice(perms, 3),
((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7))
```

Save the state for later (in reality would go into a file):

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickled = pickle.dumps(perms)
>>> type(pickled), len(pickled)
(<class 'bytes'>, 135)
```

Restore it and continue:

```
>>> restored = pickle.loads(pickled)
>>> *islice(restored, 3),
((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10))
```

Comment: Very good solution. +1 for me.. I'll try this one too

Comment: I ended up using this, thanks Kelly.